# How can I execute code after a user entered credentials but before a connection to the domain controller is established?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, authentication, events, synchronous

I'm currently moving a small office environment to Amazon Web Services (AWS). There are several domain joined computers in an office and a domain controller (DC) in an AWS Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).

A VPN connection to the VPC costs 0.05$ per connection hour and as the office is very irregularly occupied I wish to establish this connection on demand to save costs.

My thoughts were to activate this VPN connection using the AWS API everytime after a user entered its credentials. This requires me to synchronously execute code after the user submits his credentials and before Windows is trying to connect to the DC in the cloud (as this will fail when no connection is established).

Is there a way to synchronously hook in between these two steps (1. Submitting credentials, 2. Connecting to DC) and execute code?

Signing code using certificates should not be a problem.
Any other method which allows to create this VPN connection before a user enters his credentials would also be fine, like an event which is triggered as soon as the mouse is moved/key is hit/Windows 10 curtain is lifted/...

Answer (score 1):

You are pursuing a solution that won't actually solve your problem.

The per hour charge for VPN connections to VPC is for *dedicated resources and equipment* that AWS has provisioned to terminate the VPN connection.  The charge is applicable whether or not you are using it.

> If you choose to create a VPN Connection to your VPC using a Virtual Private Gateway, you are charged for each "VPN Connection-hour" that your VPN connection is provisioned and available.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/

A "VPN Connection-hour" does *not* mean an hour in which you are using it.  A VPN "connection" refers to the *provisioned* connection at AWS and it is "available" when it has been provisioned in the VPC infrastructure and is available for your use, even if your links are down and the connection is unused.

Comment: Correct, but I am able to completetly delete the connection to prevent being billed for the connection. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, you can delete the connection, but the time to create a new VPG is not short. You will also have to figure out how to put the new VPG IP addresses into your router each time. You also have the issue is that with no connection, your users cannot login nor can you "easily" hook the login processes to bring up the VPN. Look into OpenVPN for your situation.